How to handle next question in a quiz in pyTelegramBotAPI
I'm trying a multiple question quiz using telebot/pyTelegramBotAPI just like the way Telegram @QuizBot allows you to do but I'm having issue making it doing the next step.
The original code that I'm trying to work on is:
#!/usr/bin/python

# This is an example file to create quiz polls
import telebot

API_TOKEN = "<api_token>"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["poll"])
def create_poll(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "English Article Test")
    answer_options = ["a", "an", "the", "-"]

    bot.send_poll(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        question="We are going to '' park.",
        options=answer_options,
        type="quiz",
        correct_option_id=2,
        is_anonymous=False,
    )


@bot.poll_answer_handler()
def handle_poll(poll):
    # This handler can be used to log User answers and to send next poll
    print("Anything")


bot.infinity_polling()

Link on git repository
The print is not working so I'm stuck and I wasn't able to figure out how to activate the function.
I've seen register_poll_answer_handler function in the doc but I couldn't figure how to use it.

Source code: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/
Docs: https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

